# What is the order in which Chrome Extensions handle a page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Interested to find out if there is an order in which Chrome Extensions get called to handle a page.

This is of interest since extensions can modify the layout and elements of the page (for example ad blockers).

Im wondering if by the time extension x is called it operates on a page which was modified by the previous x-1 extensions and if so is there a way to control the order in which a page is 'filtered' though the various extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

you cant control the order of extension loading, but you can select if it should run right away, or idle or after the page loads its first html. see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

"run_at" manifest options for more details.